# Django queryset.filter issue with model type pgfields.ArrayField(models.DateField())

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to filter a queryset by a date range, on the model it is pgfields.ArrayField(models.DateField()) it is stored in the actual table as text[] (ide).  This is the specific piece of code that is failing

```
triage_dates = [r.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for r in list(rrule.rrule(
                rrule.DAILY,
                dtstart=parser.parse(range_start),
                until=parser.parse(range_end)
            ))]
            queryset = queryset.filter(triage_dates__overlap=triage_dates)
```

when I print the type of each item in the triage dates list, it is str, I'm getting this error on the query django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: text[] && date[].  HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I've even tried converting each item to a date as well.  I've been all over different AI platforms looking for answers.  I'm thinking I might have to convert this over to a plainsql setup but would prefer to use the ORM if possible.  I'm wondering if this is some weird bug between a postgres version + django or something.  Any insight is welcomed, thank you!